# Maven 2 "cannot find symbol" in Ubuntu, but it's fine in Windows

Tags: maven-2

When I run "mvn install" in Ubuntu system, my project got a lot of "cannot find symbol" errors, such as:

> /home/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/projects/PeerReview/arch/src/test/java/com/bleum/hydra/arch/repository/MockGuyRepositoryTest.java:[157,2] cannot find symbol 
>   symbol  : class PaginationSupport 
>   location: class com.bleum.hydra.arch.repository.MockGuyRepositoryTest 
>   /home/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/projects/PeerReview/arch/src/test/java/com/bleum/hydra/arch/repository/MockGuyRepositoryTest.java:[157,67] cannot find symbol
>   symbol  : variable Sort 
>   location: class com.bleum.hydra.arch.repository.MockGuyRepositoryTest

And seems all errors are happened in test classes.
However, when I run the same project with same command in Windows XP, everything is fine. And in Eclipse in Windows, there is no any compilation error. 
Here is Ubuntu's "mvn -v" information:

> Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-1)
>   Java version: 1.6.0_20
>   Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre
>   Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
>   OS name: "linux" version: "2.6.32-21-server" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"

Here is Windows' "mvn -v" information:

> Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-07 03:16:01+0800)
>   Java version: 1.6.0_18
>   Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre
>   Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
>   OS name: "windows xp" version: "5.1" arch: "x86" Family: "windows"

Any idea?

Comment: Does you build work on command line like mvn clean package ? Have you checked to delete your local repository first and retried it?

Comment: How about trying it using Sun (now Oracle) JDK on linux?

Comment: The classes could not be found are actually in the same project, but different package. I don't think it's local repository's problem.

Comment: Sounds like superfluous import statements? But you didn't answer the questions. Thinking is not the right way. Just check it. Furthermore without pom's it's hard to guess what's wrong.